# How can I access the email address of the logged in Auth0 user in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, auth0

I followed [this](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-symfony-app-and-adding-authentication/) tutorial to setup Oauth2 login with Auth0 in Symfony.

How can I access the email address of the logged in Auth0 user?

Notes:

- The login works successfully (oauth2 via google on the auth0 side, then redirected back)
- `$this->getUser()` from the controller shows the correct username
- scopes configured in `hwi_oauth.yaml`: `openid profile email`
- The Auth0 record (on their admin dashboard) contains email addresses for the users
- The bottom of the article references `OAuthUserProvider` to get user data but I've loaded the service and get only the username again

My code is the same as [the article I referenced](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-symfony-app-and-adding-authentication/).

This is the controller I need access to the email address in, followed by the output of the `dd($this->getUser()`.

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user", name="user")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->getUser());

        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'UserController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

> ^ HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser {#580 ▼
> #username: "coder1" }

Comment: It would be constructive to provide comments with down votes of questions.

Comment: I'ml having the same problem. The user provided by HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser only contains a single username. nothing more. I also followed the same tutorial but can find no other documentation about this. @coder1 Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend your User entity with HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser Class, and extend the HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider Class with your own.

Then register it as a service and use that in your firewall settings. Here is an article walking through it:
https://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony-hwioauthbundle-and-google-sign-in/

In your OAuthUserProvider class you can modify the loadUserByOAuthUserResponse and load your user from database.

Here are the important code pieces:

update your firewall

```
oauth_user_provider:
    service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider
```

add the services

```
hwi_oauth.user.provider.entity:
    class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider
ib_user.oauth_user_provider:
    class: Foggyline\Bundle\TickerBundle\Auth\OAuthProvider
    arguments: [@session, @doctrine, @service_container]
```

Here is the OAuthProvider class I'm using:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use App\Entity\User;

class OAuthProvider extends OAuthUserProvider
{
    protected $session, $doctrine, $admins, $userRepository;

    public function __construct($session, $doctrine, $service_container, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->container = $service_container;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $result = $this->userRepository->findBy(['name' => $username]);

        if (count($result)) {
            return $result[0];
        } else {
            return new User($username);
        }
    }

    public function loadUserByEmail($email)
    {
        $result = $this->userRepository->findBy(['email' => $email]);

        if (count($result)) {
            return $result[0];
        } else {
            return new User($email);
        }
    }

    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        //Data from response
        $email = $response->getEmail();
        $nickname = $response->getNickname();
        $realname = $response->getRealName();
        $avatar = $response->getProfilePicture();

        //set data in session
        $this->session->set('email', $email);
        $this->session->set('nickname', $nickname);
        $this->session->set('realname', $realname);
        $this->session->set('avatar', $avatar);

        $result = $this->userRepository->findBy(['email' => $email]);

        if (!count($result)) {
            $user = new User($email);
            $user->setName($realname);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

            $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword(md5(uniqid()), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($password);
        } else {
            $user = $result[0];
            $user->setUsername($realname);
        }

        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        //set id
        $this->session->set('id', $user->getId());

        return $this->loadUserByEmail($response->getEmail());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

With `$this->getUser()` you are getting UserInterface object from security token of currently logged in user. So you have access to all the regular methods of your User entity. You can do like this:

`$currentUser = $this->getUser()->getEmail();`